# If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion then so is $f\times_SId_{S'}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that the base change of a closed immersion is a closed immersion. More precisely, I want to prove that given a base scheme $S$, a morphism $\varphi:S'\rightarrow S$ and a closed immersion $f:X\rightarrow Y$ then $f\times _SId_{S'}:X\times _SS'\rightarrow Y\times_SS'$ is a closed immersion as well.

I have the following result:
$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion if and only if $f$ is affine and for every affine open subset $\operatorname{Spec} A\subset Y$ $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Spec} A)=\operatorname{Spec} B$ with the ring homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ is surjective (or equivalently if that's true for an affine cover).

I'd like to check whether my answer is correct or not (I'm self learning this stuff and I want to make sure I'm not spouting some nonsense):
We have the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S'@<p_2<<X\times_SS' @>p_1>> X\\
@V Id_{S'} V V @V f\times_S Id_{S'} VV @V fVV\\
S' @<<q_2< Y\times_SS'@>q_1>>Y
\end{CD}
We cover $S$ by affine open subsets $S_i$. Since the inverse image of $S_i$ by $Z\times_SS'\rightarrow S$ is $Z\times_{S_i}S'$ we can suppose that $S$ is affine.
We then cover $S'$ by affine open subsets $U_i$, since $q_2^{-1}(U_i)=Y\times_SU_i$ and $p_2^{-1}(U_i)=X\times_SU_i$ we get the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
U_i@<p_2<<X\times_SU_i @>p_1>> X\\
@V Id_{S'} V V @V f\times_S Id_{S'} VV @V fVV\\
U_i @<<q_2< Y\times_SU_i@>q_1>>Y
\end{CD}
We finally cover $Y$ by affine open subsets $Y_i$. Then the subsets $q_1^{-1}(Y_i)=Y_i\times_SU_i$ form an affine cover of $Y\times _SU_i$ and $(f\times_SId_{U_i})^{-1}(Y_i\times_SU_i)=f^{-1}(Y_i)\times_SU_i$. If $U_i=\operatorname{Spec} D,S=\operatorname{Spec} C,Y_i=\operatorname{Spec} B,f^{-1}(Y_i)=\operatorname{Spec}\ A$ then the ring homomorphism associated to $f\times_SId_{U_i}$ is $\psi:\begin{matrix}B\otimes_CD\rightarrow A\otimes_C D\\x\otimes y\mapsto g(x)\otimes y \end{matrix}$ where $g$ is the ring homorphism associated to $f:\operatorname{Spec} A\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} B$. $f$ is a closed immersion so $g$ is surjective and so $\psi$ is surjective as well. So $f\times_SId_{S'}$ is a closed immersion.
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: I've added `\operatorname{Spec}` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$, which looks better and plays better with spacing. Please use this in the future. As far as your work goes, looks ok.

Comment: @KReiser Okay, I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I'm trying to prove that the base change of a closed immersion is a closed immersion."

**Answer:** You may prove this by considering an open affine cover. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed immersion of schemes over $S$ and $S' \rightarrow S$ is any map, $f \times Id$ be the base change. Let $f_U:U:=Spec(A/I)  \rightarrow V:=Spec(A)$ be induced by a surjection $p:A \rightarrow A/I$ with $k \rightarrow A$ any map. Let $k \rightarrow R$ be any map. You get an exact sequence

$$ I \otimes_k R \rightarrow^{\phi} A\otimes_k R \rightarrow A/I\otimes_k R \rightarrow 0$$

Let $J:=Im(\phi) \subseteq A\otimes_k R$. There is an isomorphism

$$A\otimes_k R/J \cong (A/I)\otimes_k R$$

hence the base-change map

$$A\otimes_k R \rightarrow (A/I)\otimes_k R$$

gives rise to a closed immersion

$$Spec((A/I)\otimes_k R)\cong Spec(A\otimes_k R/J) \rightarrow Spec(A\otimes_k R).$$